# What is difference between postgres users?

Tags: postgresql, jboss, postgresql-9.2

I'm new to postgres and have some questions.
I have installed postgresql on my linux system, and it created a user postgres on the system, also i have postgres user in pgadmin, are they the same user ?

I have problem with jboss, connecting datasource causes authentication problem with password.

pg_hba.conf:

```
> # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections: host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections: host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

exception:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password
>   authentication failed for user "postgres"     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:398)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:173)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
>     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)    at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)

Comment: i got exception : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: Post that error message, the connection string and the pg_hba.conf in the question not in the comments

Comment: change line in pg_hba.conf near 127.0.0.1/32 from md5 to trust. then reload/restart postgres. If you can connect now, you provided wrong password before.

Comment: i've already tried trust, nothing changes. Password is correct, what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `pg_hba.conf` file shows every line commented out.  Were that actually the case, PostgreSQL would refuse to even start.

The `postgres` OS user and the `postgres` database role are almost completely independent.

They are connected through the fact that if you use the `peer` or `ident` forms of authentication in `pg_hba.conf`, then you need to be the `postgres` system user to log in as the `postgres` database role.  But you are not using those forms.  Also, if you do not specify which role to connect as (by using -U, for example) then many programs will default to using the name of the OS user as the name of the role to attempt to connect as.

Other than that, they are not related.  In particular they do not automatically share the same password.